# append dummy data in fetch result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*),Date(createDate) FROM EEC_Order WHERE createDate
 BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AND CURDATE()
    group by Date(createDate) ; 

COUNT(*)           Date(createDate)
  3                  2013-09-08
  1                  2013-09-11
  2                  2013-09-12
```

Above query is fetching from table that means previous 7 days from current date(assume 2013-09-13) based on  group by createdate. Results are showing 3 rows. While fetching time ,I want to add date and count in above RESULT only (not in DB) dummy date which are not there like following. Please help......How to write query for this...

```
COUNT(*)    Date(createDate)
  0                  2013-09-06
  0                  2013-09-07
  3                  2013-09-08
  0                  2013-09-09
  0                  2013-09-10
  1                  2013-09-11
  2                  2013-09-12
```

Regards
sakir
[esquareinfo](http://www.esquareinfo.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a list of the dates and a left outer join.  Here is one way to formulate the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.createDate), dates.thedate
FROM (select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) as thedate union all
      select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY ) as thedate
     ) dates left outer join
     EEC_Order o
     on Date(createDate) = dates.thedate
group by dates.thedate ;
```

EDIT:

Doing this dynamically in MySQL isn't so easy, unless you have a `numbers` or `dates` table somewhere.  The following takes this approach, by first creating a list of 1000 numbers (with a `where` clause) and then doing the join and aggregation:

```
select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL n.n DAY ), count(e.CreateDate)
from (select (n1*100 + n2*10 + n3) as n
      from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
            select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) n1 cross join
           (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
            select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) n2 cross join
           (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
            select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
           ) n3
      where (n1*100 + n2*10 + n3) <= 30
     ) n left outer join
     EEC_Order o
     on Date(createDate) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL n.n DAY )
group by DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL n.n DAY );
```

Comment: THANKS .Working fine .Is it possible for dynamically previous 30 days or couple of months or for 1 year , what to do?

Comment: Excellent.THANKS. Can u give for 30 days only please.

Comment: @ahamedsakir . . . Just change the `where` clause in the `n` subquery.

Comment: i did not understand n1,n2,n3 logic . for 30 days what to do .pls help

Comment: @ahamedsakir . . . The `n1` etc subqueries are used only to generate a derived table of numbers.  Run them separately and see what they do.